# Why is reason negative according to Hegel?

Tags: meaning

**Reason is negative and dialectical because it resolves determinations of understanding into nothing; it is positive because it generates the universal and comprehends the particular therein.** Hegel, Science of Logic, 28/1: 16

What does this mean?
Here's how I see it: reason lacks any prominent characteristics and is subjective, consisting of contradictions. To be honest this is as far as I've got.
I have never really dabbled in philosophy, so if the answer was kept simple, I suppose that would make it easer for me to understand.

Comment: I don’t know exactly what it means. I suggest you read “Reason and Revolution” by Herbert Marcuse. It is often forgotten that Marcuse was an excellent Hegel scholar. I am pretty sure it is on Internet Archive. He covers the negative well in the book I think.

Comment: There is a “not yet” involved here. To get to the actual (Reason, the better place etc) the present must give way, ie be negated. But Marcuse’s book does a mess ch better job of explaining this and putting it into context.

Comment: The quote was cut off midsentence, I edited in the missing part. According to [Houlgate, The Opening of Hegel's Logic, p.64](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xz30HFjrIFAC&source=gbs_navlinks_s):"*Hegel clearly implies that unless we are active in employing our understanding and reason we shall not be in a position to follow passively the immanent development of the categories*".

Comment: Thank you @Conifold. I think Houlgate gives some reading material too but I can’t remember if he mentions books or refers to a webpage/syllabus. (I was thinking of his lectures on YouTube. I see the book now).

Comment: I wonder if he means that in metaphysics we proceed by abduction. It eliminates ideas and is negative in this sense. Thus Bradley notes that metaphysics does not produce a positive result. It would be positive in the sense that to eliminate the impossible to is to reveal the possible. I don't understand the second half of H's sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The logic of understanding is the logic of non-contradiction : being is, non-being is not; each being is itself, and not other than itself. Understanding is a form of comprehension that is adapted to finite beings, and its concepts are those of traditional ontology, traditional " categories".

  - But understanding is not even aware of its own contardiction while rejecting the possibility of contradiction. It does not see that the assertion " no being is other than itself", precisely defines each being by a negation, by a reference to the other.
  - Reason accepts courageously this contradiction, the fact that the negative  relation to the other constitutes every being in itself. According to reason, A = A is a result , that is, self identity is  mediated by self -alterity  : A is not not A, not being A is part of what it means to be A. ( The " *aliquid"*  - the something - is essentially " *aliud quid*".)
  - Since every being has its being in the other, every being contradicts itself: the law of being is the law of contradiction, hence the law of mouvement, ofbecoming.
  - Contradiction is the negative side of Reason. Contradiction overcome ( contradiction contradicted at the level of the Universal, from the point of view of the " Whole") is the positive aspect of Reason.